# Create users on Microsoft Active Directory using a Scripting Language

Tags: python, active-directory

I need to create and/or update the Students users in the school I work in. I only have access to the "Remote Control" not directly on the server and I have been told, that I will be able to remotely create, update and delete users and groups.

The problem is: I must create a lot users every 1/2 Year and so, I want to do that automatically. I have a database dump from the students and the classes so I could read that out in a scripting language like Python, PHP or in a Java/C++ program (Python would be my favourite)

I am looking for a way to create the groups and the users with a scripting lanugage on a remote computer and if it also works I want to create sharedrives and give the users/groups access to that automatically.

Each half year, the users get updated in the new class so I must fetch a record of the users and check it against the new students list and update the users.

Does anyone know some bindings/remote controll libraries/classes for Microsoft Active Directory Management for one of those Programming Languages?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I've used PyAD for AD-work and was satisfied with the result. Here is a short example of creating a user.

```
from pyad import *
pyad.set_defaults(ldap_server="dc1.domain.com", username="service_account", password="mypassword")
ou = ADContainer.from_dn("ou=users, dc=domain, dc=com")
new_user = ADUser.create("Daniel", ou, password="Secret")
```

It is also possible to edit users and groups using `set_attribute` and add users to groups. For example:

```
new_user.set_attribute("mail", "daniel@example.com")
group = ADGroup.from_dn("so-users")
group.add_member(new_user)
```

And to delete:

```
new_user.delete()
```

You can find the documentation at: https://zakird.com/pyad/

Note: I do not have access to a Windows environment so this code isn't tested, so expect some detail to be wrong.